# I want to add Button or hyper links

Tags: views

I want add a Download Button, as far as I know that means the posted content contains Buttons.

now I add the CKeditor for the purpose. When post content users have to use HTML ,But not all the users know HTML,

then What should I do

Comment: I think you might want to use Link module to add a new Link field so your users can enter the Link and a title. You can have a field template to style the link as a button or whatever.

Comment: @AyeshK thanks, I will try the Link module.

but I have no idea the said "You can have a field template to style the link as a button or whatever" ,Can u explain it more specifically. Thanks again.

Comment: Once you have Link module installed, you will be able to theme the output of the link. By default, it's a regular anchor tag with normal valid markup. If you add a new field template (http://drupal.org/node/1089656), you can override this output and make modifications, for an example, add specific attributes to the anchor tag to the output.